# Cannot open file in java

Tags: java

I am trying to open a text file in java. I am using ubuntu 12.04. Following is my code:

```
package nlp;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class sentence {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("hello");
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("test.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        // process the line.
    }
    br.close();

}

}
```

I am using Eclipse for development. It says "FileNotFound". I have put the text file in .class as well as .java folder. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: hint: try `new File(".").getAbsolutePath()`in order to know where your file is searched.

Comment: Probably the path to your test.txt file is wrong. Where is that file stored?

Comment: The way your code is it's assuming the file is in the same directory as the executable. And even then you definitely want to grab the 'AbsolutePath' just as good practice

Answer (score 4):

The default execution directory in Eclipse is the root of the project folder. Put the file there or prefix the path with correct underlying folder structure.

Comment: By correct folder structure, do you mean = "/home/Documents/test.txt". I have tried with complete path, still of no avail!

Answer (score 1):

you need to put that in try-catch because it throws IOException which is checked Exception.Put the code in try-catch or handle the exception using "public static void main(String[] args)  throws IOException"

Comment: Is is indeed a good practice but does not solve the OP's problem.

Comment: How the code will compile without handling checked Exception ? Is it possible in any case?

Answer (score 1):

The file should be in root of the project folder as given below. Your code is working fine.

[image: eclipse workspace]

Answer (score 0):

As Arnaud mentioned try this to find where Java is expecting the file:

```
System.out.println(new File(".").getAbsolutePath());
```